Brahmagupta's Identity for Pell's Equations in Engel's Book
I was reading Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel (Chapter 6 p. 128) when I came across

$x^2 - dy^2 = 1\phantom{a}$ (1)

and

We associate the number $x+y\sqrt{d}$ with every solution $(x,y)$. We have the basic factorization $$x^2 - dy^2 = (x-y\sqrt{d})(x+y\sqrt{d}) \phantom{iii} (2)$$
It follows from (2) that the product or quotient of two solutions of (1) is again a solution of (1).

The way the book says this seems to suggest that this is a somewhat trivial observation, but I don't see it. I think I am aware of Brahmagupta's identity which says that the solutions are closed under multiplication but it seems that the algebra is somewhat involved. Can someone explain if there is a simple way to see how equation (2) shows that the solutions are closed under multiplication and division? Thanks.

FYI, from Wikipedia's History section of its "Pell's equation" article, there's "In Indian mathematics, Brahmagupta discovered that $(x_{1}^{2}-Ny_{1}^{2})(x_{2}^{2}-Ny_{2}^{2})=(x_{1}x_{2}+Ny_{1}y_{2})^{2}-N(x_{1}y_{2}+x_{2}y_{1})^{2}$".

simple way to show how solutions of (1) are "closed under multiplication":  if $x_1^2-dy_1^2=1$ and $x_2^2-dy_2^2=1$ then $(x_1-y_1\sqrt d)(x_1+y_1\sqrt d)(x_2-y_2\sqrt d)(x_2+y_2\sqrt d)=1$, so $((x_1x_2+dy_1y_2)-(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)\sqrt d)((x_1x_2+dy_1y_2)+(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)\sqrt d)=1$, so $(x_1x_2+dy_1y_2)^2-d(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)^2=1$

I would not say "multiplication or division."  The following things are true:  there really is a "fundamental solution"  $x_0^2 - n y_0^2 = 1$  where both $x_0, y_0 \neq 0$  and $|x_0| + | y_0 | $   minimal  among nonzero solutions. Then $$ A  = \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
x_0 & n y_0 \
y_0 & x_0 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$  or its inverse takes any solution to another; in the forward direction that is the mapping of pairs $(x,y) \mapsto (x_0 x + n y_0 y,  y_0 x + x_0 y)$

Solutions are elements of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$ of norm $1,$ so it follows immediately from multiplicativity of the norm:  $N(\alpha)=1=N(\beta)\Rightarrow N(\alpha\beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)=1\cdot 1 = 1,$ where multiplicativity of the norm follows from multiplicativity  of conjugation, i.e.  $N(\alpha\beta)= \alpha\beta\overline{\alpha\beta} = \alpha\bar\alpha,\beta\bar\beta = N(\alpha)N(\beta).\ \ $ This question is - of course -  a duplicate of many others.
